# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else, stumped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

so I'm making a nav menu that has a slide toggle. I want the toggle button to hide when the menu is open but I still want it to occupy the space so as to not mess up formatting.

My javascript code is as follows:

```
(function() {
$('.menu-toggle').bind('click',function() {
                $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
                if ($('body').hasClass('menu-open') == true) {
                    $('.outside-toggle').style.visibility = "hidden";
                else
                    $('.outside-toggle').style.visibility = "visible";
                };
    return false;
});
```

})();

I have tried a number of different syntax conventions and none of them seem to work. I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `else` has to be outside of `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if ($('body').hasClass('menu-open') == true) {
    $('.outside-toggle').style.visibility = "hidden";
else
    $('.outside-toggle').style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

to

```
if ($('body').hasClass('menu-open')) { // == true is useless
    $('.outside-toggle')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"; // missing [0]
} else { // <------ HERE THE MISSING BRACES
    $('.outside-toggle')[0].style.visibility = "visible"; // style is a property of a DOM element, not of a jquery object
}
```

or better:

```
$('.outside-toggle').css('visibility', $('body').hasClass('menu-open') ? "hidden" : "visible");
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that..Thanks, Denys

Comment: I have changed the that section to 
$('.outside-toggle').style.visibility = $('body').hasClass('menu-open') ? "hidden" : "visible";
The code now returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined"

Comment: Thank you, the code now works. What is the function of the [0]?

Comment: Additionally, is there a way to set a transition effect?

Comment: [0] returns the DOM element from the jQuery object. To set a transition look for the fadeOut function or use css transitions  like this: http://jsbin.com/viyujejije/1/watch?html,css,js,output (click "Run with JS")